# Why average energy of gas particles in equilibrium is $\bar{\epsilon}=E / N$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation, ideal-gas

Reif, statistical physics

- (By random the author means "A situation, which can be obtained in many different ways". The most random situation therefore means the situation that can be obtained in most number of ways)
- Average energy of a particle is calculated as  $\frac{1}{T} \int e \cdot d t$ over a sufficiently long time interval

> "Hence the basic question becomes:
> How is the fixed total energy of the gas distributed over the individual
> molecules? It is possible that one group of molecules might have very
> high energies while another group might have very low energies. But this kind of situation is quite special and would not persist as the molecules collide with each other and thus exchange energy.The time independent equilibrium situation which is ultimately attained corresponds therefore to the most random distribution of the total energy of the gas over all the molecules. Each molecule has then, on the average, the same energy and thus also the same speed"

The author suggests that the most random distribution implies that the average energy of each particle is $E/N$.

I'm not able to see the link between the most random distribution and average energy.

Using this definition of equilibrium as the  most random situation how can I deduce that the average energy of a gas particle in equilibrium is $\bar{\epsilon}=E / N$. Where does the idea of "most random situation" enter the argument?

Answer (score 2):

Its straight forward, if you have N particles and total energy E, the average is E/N. Equilibrium means that E doesn't change.

Comment: Where does the "most random" enter the argument then?

Comment: @Kashmiri, you need to know it's in the equilibrium ("most random") state to know that "the average number of molecules in any subvolume $V_s$ is ...", or to know that the particles in one subvolume will have the same average energy as the average for the whole volume.

Comment: @The Photon, I am still not able to understand. Can you please help me.

Comment: OK we have the most random situation, then how can I say each particle on average has same energy as E/N ?

Comment: "most random" could refer to entropy, with an equilibrium macroscopic state with the most microstates and hence being most probable or "most random". I dont like or fully understand the term.

Comment: @Karsten B, please see the edited post. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: @Kashmiri, the average of *N* samples of some parameter *x* is always $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$. You don't need to know that the system is "most random" to know that the average of the particle energies in some sample is given by this formula. You need to know that it is most random to know that if you measure a sample  from some particular subvolume is representative of the whole volume.

Comment: @The Photon please see the edited lost. Also Why then does the author write "The time independent equilibrium situation which is ultimately attained corresponds therefore to the most random distribution of the total energy of the gas over all the molecules. Each molecule has then, on the average, the same energy and thus also the same speed" ?

Comment: I think the author assumes that the system will find an stable equlibrium in a overall  maximum for the entropy over time, inspired by the second law of thermodynamics: "Entrophy tends to increase". Therefore this equlibrium is  "most random". The energy average beeing E/N wiĺl on the other hand hold for any stable (time independent) equlibrium "most random" or not.